# How to generate OpenAPI Swagger from Avro schema

Tags: swagger, avro, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to create an OpenAPI schema(swagger yaml) from an avro schema using the open api generator tool. But not able to identify is that supported to not.
Is there another way to get OpenAPI schema from an avro schema either using any online tool or programmatically?

Comment: Openapi spec doesn't adhere to Avro. If this were possible, it'd only be a subset

Comment: See: https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/avro.jsp
Found here: https://forum.confluent.io/t/how-to-generate-openapi-swagger-from-avro-schema/1503